# selecting object in data structure

Tags: javascript, arrays

How would you make an new object with just animal/weight key/value pairs from the following object?

```
{
    "Pigs": {
        "Weight": 6.2,
        "Price": 1.6
    },
    "Chicken": {
        "Weight": 5.8,
        "Price": 0.9
    },
  ...
```

Comment: Can you explain yourself? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
 var a={ "Pigs": { "Weight": 6.2, "Price": 1.6 }, "Chicken": { "Weight": 5.8, "Price": 0.9 }}
 var g={};

 for (var o in a)
  {
    g[o]=a[o].Weight;
  }

 console.log(g) //Object {Pigs: 6.2, Chicken: 5.8}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
var a = {
    "pigs" :   { "Weight": 6.2, "Price": 1.6 },
    "Chicken": { "Weight": 5.8, "Price": 0.9 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
var objects = jQuery.parseJSON('{ "Pigs": { "Weight": 6.2, "Price": 1.6 }, "Chicken": { "Weight": 5.8, "Price": 0.9 }}');

var animals = [];

for (object in objects) {
    animals[object] = objects[object].Weight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be like this:

```
var animals = {animel1:"Pigs", animal2:"Chicken"};
animals.animel1.wight=6.2;
animals.animel1.price=1,6;
.
.
.
```

and so on